# Python. Second step of subprocess.Popen truncates results of first

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess, chaining

In the snipet of my python script below, I think that temp2 doesn't wait for temp to finish running, the output can be large, but is just text. This truncates the result ('out') from temp, it stops mid line. 'out' from temp works fine until temp 2 is added. I tried adding time.wait() as well as subprocess.Popen.wait(temp). These both allow temp to run to completion so that 'out' is not truncated but disrupt the chaining process so that there is no 'out2'. Any ideas?

```
temp = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#time.wait(1)
#subprocess.Popen.wait(temp)
temp2 =  subprocess.Popen(call2, stdin=temp.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = temp.communicate()
out2, err2 = temp2.communicate()
```

Comment: do you need the output from `temp` in your script and to pipe it to `temp2` (something like `tee` utility) or do you want only to pipe it to `temp2` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) communicate() can accept a stream to be sent as input. If you change `stdin` of `temp2` to `subprocess.PIPE` and put `out` in communicate(), the data is properly piped.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import time

call = ["echo", "hello\nworld"]
call2 = ["grep", "w"]

temp = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

temp2 =  subprocess.Popen(call2, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = temp.communicate()
out2, err2 = temp2.communicate(out)

print("Out:  {0!r}, Err:  {1!r}".format(out, err))
# Out:  b'hello\nworld\n', Err:  None
print("Out2: {0!r}, Err2: {1!r}".format(out2, err2))
# Out2: b'world\n', Err2: None
```

Comment: It loads the whole output from `temp` into memory but OP says that the output can be large. You could use `subprocess.check_output()` if you don't mind loading the output into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Following ["Replacing shell pipeline" section from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
temp = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
temp2 =  subprocess.Popen(call2, stdin=temp.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
temp.stdout.close()
out2 = temp2.communicate()[0]
```